# Equivalent to BIT_OR function in SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, aggregate

I have code that runs against a MySQL database but the unit tests for the code use SQLite.

The issue is one code method uses a SQL query which aggregates using the `BIT_OR` function of MySQL. Is there an equivalent or a way to replicate its functionality in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports using the pipe symbol as a bitwise-OR operator, as in:

```
SELECT col1 | col2
FROM sometable;
```

So, if `col1` contains `1` and `col2` contains `2`, the result would be `3`.

[Here's a SQLFiddle.uk demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f76acb9e09b78d5f4f21db7b2b502f25) showing how that works under SQLite 3.27.